# Block based UIAlertView with ARC

Tags: ios, categories

I'm reading iOS 5 pushing the limits, and the author has an example of block-based alert views.  Here's the code:

.h

```
typedef void (^DismissBlock)(int buttonIndex);
typedef void (^CancelBlock)();

+ (UIAlertView *)showAlertViewWithTitle:(NSString *)title
                                message:(NSString *)message
                      cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle
                      otherButtonTitles:(NSArray *)otherButtons
                              onDismiss:(DismissBlock)dismissed
                               onCancel:(CancelBlock)cancelled;
```

.m

```
static DismissBlock _dismissBlock;
static CancelBlock _cancelBlock;

+ (UIAlertView *)showAlertViewWithTitle:(NSString *)title
                                message:(NSString *)message
                      cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle
                      otherButtonTitles:(NSArray *)otherButtons
                              onDismiss:(DismissBlock)dismissed
                               onCancel:(CancelBlock)cancelled {
    [_cancelBlock release];
    _cancelBlock = [cancelled copy];
    [_dismissBlock release];
    _dismissBlock = [dismissed copy];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:[self self] cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles: nil];

    for (NSString *buttonTitle in otherButtons) {
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:buttonTitle];
    }
    [alert show];

    return [alert autorelease];
}

+ (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) {
        _cancelBlock();
    }
    else {
        _dismissBlock(buttonIndex - 1); // cancel button is index 0
    }
    [_cancelBlock autorelease];
    [_dismissBlock autorelease];
}
```

I had a couple questions regarding this implementation.

1) If I'm using ARC, in the showAlertViewWithTitle method, do I need to release the block before I copy it?  Why or why not?

2) In showAlertViewWithTitle: method, he assigns the delegate:[self self].  How does this actually work?  I haven't seen this notation before.

3) Why are there static variables declared for the dismiss and cancel blocks?  Is this basically serving as an ivar for this Category?

Thanks!

Comment: Why `_dismissBlock(buttonIndex - 1);` and why not `_dismissBlock(buttonIndex);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) When using ARC you can't make any calls to release or autorelease so no, you don't need to call release. ARC will take care of that for you when you assign the copy.

2) I've never seen that either. I just use 'self'.

3) Categories can't have ivars. The use of statics here is dangerous and will only work if you are 100% positive that you will never call this **showAlertViewWithTitle:...** class method while an alert view is currently displayed.

Personally, I wouldn't make this a category method to UIAlertView due to the need for the statics. I'd create a regular class (MyAlertView or similar) that extends UIAlertView and adds a new 'show' method that takes the two block parameters. Then your custom class can have proper ivars for the blocks.